# Update a collection thru lamdada expression or direct in database with EF 4.1

Tags: lambda, entity-framework-4.1

I have a collection of object (Invoices) that I want to mark in the database thru EF 4.1 that I am working on, so nobody else will grab them and work on them.

This is how I do it today.

```
  ICollection<Invoice> affectedInvoices = _inputDataRepository.GetNewInvoices();

  DateTime processingTime = DateTime.Now
  foreach (Invoice invoice in affectedInvoices )
       invoice.ProcessingDate = ProcessingTime

  _inputDataRepository.UpdateInvoices(invoicesToBeMarked);
```

Now I have 2 questions. Is there a way to use a lamda expression to set the ProcessingDate instead of the loop, there must be, but I can't figure it out..

When I Save this collection to database thru EF 4.1. Will it be so smart so it can convert all this Updates into 1 like this.

```
UPDATE [Invoices] SET ProcessingDate = '2011-08-05 12:00:00' WHERE ID IN (1,2,3,4....)
```

Or will it be as many UPDATE Statements to SQL that I have invoices in my collection. If that is the case, is there some way to fire away an SQLStatement to the database thru the EF DbContext.

If thats the case then I don't have to open a new connection and create specific code for that...

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`foreach` is the right way to modify data. You should not modify a collection or its members in a query expression. Remember, query expressions are usually working with lazy enumerators.

No, EF won't convert to `WHERE ID IN...`.

Yes, you can execute SQL directly. Use [ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.executestorecommand.aspx).